# Declare bibliography option ending on biblatex

Tags: biblatex, options

Greetings from the Swiss Alps,

I would like to submit the following problem:

My intention is to create a new bibliography option which I can toggle at wish while loading the package `biblatex-swiss-legal`.

### The general context

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=biblatex-swiss-legal-general,backend=biber,autolang=other,jurisdictionindex=true,commentarystyle=styleA]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Referencingtest.bib}

% Bibliography entries (using JabRef)

@Commentary{bskor1,     % This is the main entry, from which the customa (smaller)
location   = {Basel},   % citations  will be created, it only appears in the bibliography
date       = {2015},
title      = {Basler Kommentar. Obligationenrecht},
titleaddon = {OR},
editor     = {Honsell, Heinrich and Vogt, Nedim Peter and Wiegand, Wolfgang},
edition    = {6},
series     = {bsk},
volume     = {I},
}

@Customa{bsk19/20or,    % This entry will appear in the document
crossref = {bskor1},
author   = {Huguenin, Claire and Meize, Barbara},
part     = {19/20},
}
```

I would like to change the `commentarystyle` to `styleD` designed as following in the `.bbx` file:

```
\newbibmacro{customa:styleD}{% <-- This is actually a test, not having any idea 
\bibsstring{\thefield{series}}%    how it will look like, being unable to make it appear
\printtext{-}%                     on the pdf result
\printnames{labelname}%
\addcomma\addspace%
\printfield{titleaddon}\addspace%
\printfield{part}%
}%
```

And would supposably look like the:

> BsK-Huguenin/Meize, OR 19/20 N 12.

Styles A, B and C look like this (these are somewhat modified compared to the original package, most of it concerning the punctuation without the use of `\newblock` nor `\newunit`):

```
\newbibmacro{customa:styleA}{%
\iffieldbibstring{series}%
{\bibsstring{\thefield{series}}}%
{\printfield{series}}%
\iffieldundef{series}{}{\printtext{-}}\printnames{labelname}\addcomma%
\iffieldundef{type}%
{%
\iftoggle{bbx:adarticle}%
    {\addspace}%
    {\addspace}%
}%
{%
\iffieldbibstring{type}%
    {\bibsstring{\thefield{type}}}%
    {\printfield{type}}%
\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{part}%
{}%
{\iftoggle{bbx:adarticle}%
    {\bibsstring{ad}\addspace}%
    {}%
\ifboolexpr{%
test {\iffieldequalstr{series}{beckkuko}}
or
test {\iffieldequalstr{series}{mnk}}
or
test {\iffieldequalstr{series}{nmk}}
or
test {\iffieldequalstr{series}{palandt}}
or
test {\iffieldequalstr{series}{stk}} 
}
{% Si le commentaire est allemand (DEU)
    \ifboolexpr{% Test pour savoir s'il y a plusieurs articles
    test {\IfSubStr{\thefield{part}}{-}}
    or 
    test {\IfSubStr{\thefield{part}}{f.}}
    or 
    test {\IfSubStr{\thefield{part}}{ff.}}
    or 
    test {\IfSubStr{\thefield{part}}{\psq}}
    or 
    test {\IfSubStr{\thefield{part}}{\psqq}}
    }
    {\bibstring{articlesde}}
    {\bibstring{articlede}}
}% 
{\bibsstring{article}}% Si le commentaire n'est pas allemand (donc suisse)
\addspace\printfield{part}%
}%
\addspace%
\printfield{titleaddon}%
}

\newbibmacro{customa:styleB}{%
\iffieldundef{series}
{\usebibmacro{customa:styleA}}% Si les séries ne sont pas définies, utilisation du style A
{\iffieldbibstring{series}%
{\bibsstring{\thefield{series}}\printtext{-}}%
{\iffieldundef{series}%
    {}%
    {\printfield{series}\printtext{-}}%
}%
\iffieldundef{titleaddon}%
{}%
{\printfield{titleaddon}\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{volume}%
{}%
{\thefield{volume}}%
\addcomma\addspace%
\printnames{labelname}%
\iffieldundef{type}%
{%
\iftoggle{bbx:adarticle}%
    {\addspace}%
    {\addspace}%
}%
{\addcomma\addspace%
\iffieldbibstring{type}{\bibsstring{\thefield{type}}}{\printfield{type}}%
\newunit}%
\iffieldundef{part}%
{}%
{\iftoggle{bbx:adarticle}%
    {\bibsstring{ad}\newunit}%
    {}%
\addcomma\addspace\bibsstring{article}\addspace\printfield{part}%
}%
}}%



\newbibmacro{customa:styleC}{%
\iftoggle{bbx:firstnames}
{\printnames{author}}%
{\printnames{labelname}}%
\iffieldundef{series}%
{}%
{\newblock\usebibmacro{printin}%
\iffieldbibstring{series}%
    {\biblstring{\thefield{series}}}%
    {\printfield{series}}%
}%
\iffieldundef{type}%
{%
\iftoggle{bbx:adarticle}%
    {\newunit}%
    {\newblock}%
}%
{\newblock%
\iffieldbibstring{type}{\bibsstring{\thefield{type}}}{\printfield{type}}%
\newunit}%
\iffieldundef{part}%
{}%
{\iftoggle{bbx:adarticle}%
    {\bibsstring{ad}\newunit}%
    {}%
\bibsstring{article}\addspace\printfield{part}%
}%
\addcomma\addspace%
\printfield{titleaddon}%
}
```

The respective styles as citation look as following:

Style A:

> BsK-Huguenin/Meize, Art. 19/20 OR, N 12.

Style B:

> BsK-OR I, Huguenin/Meize, Art. 19/20, N 12.

Style C:

> Huguenin/Meize, in: Basler Kommentar, Art. 19/20 OR, N 12.

N.B.:

- authors are supposed to be in small caps;
- the German version of the package is being used;
- "N 12" is side margin number used in Swiss commentaries, and is defined with `\footcite` command through this `\providecommand{\chaparN}[2]{\S~#1 \parN #2}` command created by the author.

I should mention that `style C` isn't of any use for my kind of papers, yet I'd prefer keeping the option open, should I need it.

### My problem

I'm *not* seeking help concerning the part immediately above, rather more for what follows:

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{commentarystyle}{%
 \ifcsdef{blx@opt@commentarystyle@#1}
{\blx@commentarystyle\csuse{blx@opt@commentarystyle@#1}}
{\blx@err@invopt{commentarystyle=#1}{}}}
\cslet{blx@opt@commentarystyle@styleA}\z@
\let\blx@opt@commentarystyle@styleB\@ne
\let\blx@opt@commentarystyle@styleC\tw@
\let\blx@opt@commentarystyle@styleD\ % this is where I'm having trouble.
```

Without the last ligne, I can't load the pkg with the `styleD` option, but I can't figure out what the ending (coming after the last `\`, like `z@`, `@ne`, `tw@` for styles A, B and C respectively), since if I copy one of the other styles, the said style is used instead of the `styleD`.

Anyone has an idea on what combination of letters and `@` to add at the end of the last line to make it possible to load?

Cheers,

Archein

#### The additional infos

P.S.: if you ever go looking at the original `biblatex-swiss-legal` package, it's actually quite old (Jan 2014) and doesn't take into consideration the new biblatex/biber changes since then, I already corrected the file.

P.S.S.: I beg for mercy if this question might seem stupid or easy to solve, I still new and trying to get my hands on biblatex.

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the `commentarystyle` option to choose your style? If not you could just do `\newbibmacro{customa:styleA}` and overwrite the `A` style (analogous for `B` or `C`). The code to switch between the style looks mighty complicated right now, but that could also be tackled if you insist.

Comment: (BTW: Please not that your MWE is not actuallyan MWE. This question probably doesn't need one - and it would not be easy to create one anyway since the `biblatex` style will probably throw all sorts of errors with a recent `biblatex` version. But for future reference, [here's what makes a good MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)).

Comment: @moewe: no no, I would like to maintain styles A, B and C if possible, while still creating a new D style of my own for special kinds of documents.

Comment: (I'll make due note of that for the future, thanks! :) )

Comment: @moewe This is going to be pretty hard to answer with a more complete example, though. If we don't know what changes have been made to the style, it is hard to be sure what will not conflict. Moreover, it is impossible to test any solution without updating that file to make it work with current packages. Since the OP has already done that, a link to the updated version (probably would need to be renamed for licence reasons) would surely make it easier. That's not an MWE, but an MWE wouldn't do any harm for testing, either.

Comment: You could probably just use `\newcommand*\my@four{4}\let\blx@opt@commentarystyle@styleD\my@four`. At least, it isn't obvious why not. But without updating the entire style myself and creating an MWE, I obviously have no idea whether it works or not. (Probably not - I always miss something, usually several somethings.)

Comment: @cfr Testing is a problem, definitely. But the problem itself is clear enough from the description once one has a look at `biblatex-swiss-legal-base.bbx`, I believe.

Comment: @all: I hope the additional info is useful for resolving the problem, if not, feel free too cancel what's useless

Comment: The code we have now is still not an MWE. The additional code does not really help. cfr is right that in this particular case we would probably have to see the entire `biblatex-swiss-legal-base.bbx` since you will have to have applied quite some changes to the original file (but beware of license issues, you might have to rename the file if you publish it). If my answer works for you though, that is not all that important. (For future reference though it is good to keep in mind.)

Answer (score 3):

The code in `biblatex-swiss-legal-base.bbx` for the selection of the `customa` style is not that easily extensible. We can make it though.

Replace the `\DeclareBibliographyOption{commentarystyle}` block with

```
\providebibmacro{customa:full}{}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[string]{commentarystyle}{%
  \ifcsdef{abx@macro@customa:#1}
    {\renewbibmacro{customa:full}{%
       \testibid{\usebibmacro{customa:#1}}}}
    {\blx@err@invopt{commentarystyle=#1}{you need to define the bibmacro 'customa:#1'}}}
```

Then you only need to move the `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` code to the very end of the `.bbx` file to avoid premature errors.

From now on you can order `commentarystyle=<styleX>`, if the bibmacro `customa:<styleX>` is defined otherwise an error is issued.